# Change div background on click and on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change picture in div on mouse over and on click using JS. Like that:

```
    var favs = document.getElementsByClassName("fav-wrapper");
    for (var i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {
    favs[i].innerHTML = '<img src="images/favorite.png" />';
    favs[i].onMouseOver = function () {
        favs[i].innerHTML = "<img src='images/favorite_hover.png' />";
    }
    favs[i].onClick = function () {
        favs[i].innerHTML = "<img src='images/favorite_on.png' />";
    };
}
```

But for some reason it won't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Event handlers are all lowercase

Comment: Also note that if you do get the event handlers working, your code is not going to work the right way. When the events are triggered they will set the innerHTML of the last element in the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try lowercase event handlers and actually you need a closure to have the [i] work inside the loop. I prefer using `this` in your case.

```
var favs = document.getElementsByClassName("fav-wrapper");
for (var i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {
  favs[i].innerHTML = '<img src="images/favorite.png" />';
  favs[i].onmouseover = function () {
    this.innerHTML = "<img src='images/favorite_hover.png' />";
  }
  favs[i].onclick = function () {
    this.innerHTML = "<img src='images/favorite_on.png' />";
  }
}
```

but why not just change the src of the images?

```
var favs = document.getElementsByClassName("fav-wrapper");
for (var i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {
  var fav=favs[i];
  fav.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src="images/favorite.png";
  fav.onmouseover = function () {
    this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src="images/favorite_hover.png";
  }
  fav.onmouseout = function () {
    this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src="images/favorite.png";
  }
  fav.onclick = function () {
    this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src="images/favorite_on.png";
  }
}
```

you could do all this with CSS by the way

Comment: Yep, "this" fixes it. But how do I change picture back when I move mouse  away from that div?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! About your remark that I could do all that stuff with CSS — AFAIK I won't be able to toggle images on click and the image would change only for the moment it's being clicked. Am I Right?  Probably I could achieve such behavior by making kinda fake checkbox...

Comment: Here is a pure CSS button 
https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/d0cnoxdb/ it is styled via http://usabilitypost.com/2012/01/10/pressed-button-state-with-css3/

Answer (score 2):

you can try this method using pure css changing background on hover and on click

```css
.image{width:500px;height:500px;background-image: url("http://www.toolsformoney.com/financial_software_demos.jpg");background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.image:hover{background-image: url("http://www.hostpph.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/free-bookie-software-demo-large.jpg");background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.image:focus{background-image: url("https://www.arxan.com/wp-content/uploads/assets1/images/demo.png");background-repeat: no-repeat;outline: 0;transition:0s;}
```

```html
<div class="image" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that in such a way the image won't last after it's clicked, the clicked version will stay only while the mouse button is being clicked

Comment: @mplungjan how about now

Comment: Pretty nice. But the downside is that the image returns to original state if I click somewhere else on the document, while it should preserve it's clicked state until clicked once more